# "He gives his take on fatherhood"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have already seen this phrase (give take on + sth) on newspapers. Though I looked it up in dictionaries, I wouldn't find it. I'm very keen of learning English.

what is the meaning of "He gives his take on fatherhood".

Comment: What exactly did you look up in dictionaries? And which dictionaries? Did you, for example, look up the [noun senses of the word _take_](http://i.word.com/idictionary/take) (especially sense 5 here)? That should give you your answer.

Comment: I'll give you my take: If you're keen on learning English, you may want to create a second account on [ell.se]. That's probably a better place for questions like this one. You can get more information [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/), where I gave my take on the differences between the two sites.

Answer (score 2):

To give one's take on an issue means to **express one's opinion** or **express one's point of view** on it.

See nos. 100-101 in [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take) as well as the forum discussion [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/give-ones-own-take-on.2733985/).